# Applying full-time to company I rejected for internship? Do I bring this up?

Tags: job-search, internship, email

I am now a senior applying to jobs full time in industry X.

Last summer, companies A and B offered me internships. I went with B but realized, in the end, A probably would have been a better fit. So I am applying to A full time.

- When I apply, is it seen as a positive or negative that I was offered an internship but didn't take it?
- And what can I do to best increase my chances of getting a FT offer?

  - Do I email the same recruiter that walked me through the internship process?
  - If so, what would I say?

EDIT: The recruiter is a campus recruiter with that many campuses, so I am fairly  (60%) sure he would remember me. I am not sure if this changes anything.

Comment: Can't tell what somebody is thinking, so no idea how they would feel about you turning down an internship with them.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, some companies will not be organized enough to keep track of the fact that you once applied to be an intern there. There's a decent chance that they won't even remember you.

Second, if they do interview you and ask why you rejected the opportunity to work there as an intern you can honestly reply that you wanted to explore other options at the time, but that as a recent graduate you are interested in employment with them.

They may push and probe as to why that is, in which case avoid comparing companies A and B. Instead, focus on why company A is a great choice for you, and how you would enhance their team.

Comment: Not sure if this changes anything, but the recruiter is a campus recruiter for a small schools -- so I think he would remember me. Does this change whether it would be useful to reach out to him to let him know I am interested in the role?

Comment: @thewhitetie - no, your goal is the same. The recruiter will not personally care whether you once rejected an offer (if he's professional). If they wanted you as a student then they should be even happier with the more experienced version of the same person. Worst case scenario apply to that company through some other way.

Answer (score 0):

> When I apply, is it seen as a positive or negative that I was offered an internship but didn't take it?

Neither. People accept and decline offers for many reasons.

> And what can I do to best increase my chances of getting a FT offer?

Get time in-person with the campus recruiter if you can.
Talk to him/her about the position you are interested in and show him/her your resume/CV and ask if there is anything you can do to improve it before you apply.